# How to restore user's workstate using PHP.?

Tags: php, html

I have a webpage form that exchanges data with database. I have handled some errors in another php page that sends the validation results to the current page. But when it shows the errors all the values go away from the form fields. I want to know how can i save these data and then restore it to the fields? Or is there any better way to do this? How?

Comment: Do you plan to add some code My Friend? Your form & it's handler code would be great to resolve your issue.

Comment: A few ways, Store the user form inputs in $_SESSION, $_COOKIE, HTML5 storage or even pass back as url query parameters.

Comment: I have lots of text fields.  Can i save an array into the session variables?

Comment: @user3506714 yes you can

Comment: i suggest follow loz's idea, store the users input temporarily first, and then use it again if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must save these in session.

```
$_SESSION["secretword"] = "ABC123" ;
```

You can assign as many variables as you wish.

To access those variables, simply reference it as you would any PHP array.

```
session_start();
$secretword = $_SESSION["secretword"] ;
```

hope this helps!